# How to Retrieve a list of top-level collection of Documents of this type? any one with a solution

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

I need to display contents of all documents Ids in an array
[image]

I  am using firebase with Flutter;

this is my function :

```
   getlist()async{
     var snapshot = await _firestore.collection("posts").get();
    var data = snapshot.docs.map((doc)=> doc.data());
   return data;
     }
```

[I need to able to  access top-level collection of this type any one with a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5YnJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all your help support.but this how i managed to solve my problem.

`CollectionReference _collectionRef = _firestore.collection("posts"); QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get(); final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();`

Answer (score 1):

Try using ".toList()"

Comment: Try Google "call api then put it in one list"